# Autenticação laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticação

Estou tentando fazer login no laravel 5.2 mas não está autenticando o usuario na tabela.

no arquivo `auth.php` alterei a tabela de validação para `login`:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'login',
        ],
```

E setei a classe Login:

```
 'providers' => [
        'login' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Login::class,
        ],
```

Criei meu Model em `App\Login` :

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Login extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

E no caminho `Http/Controllers/LoginController.php`criei o controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends BaseController
{

    public function logar(Request $req) {
        $validator = Validator($req->all(), [
           'email' => 'required',
           'password' => 'required' 
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('candidato/login')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        }

        $credenciais = ['email' => $req->input('email'), 'password' => $req->input('password')];

        dd(Auth::attempt($credenciais));

        if(Auth::attempt($credenciais, true)) {
            return redirect('candidato/perfil');
        } else {
            return redirect('candidato/login')
                    ->withErrors(['errors' => 'login inválido'])
                    ->withInput();
        }
    } 
}
```

Só que ele sempre cai no `else`, mesmo tendo o usuário no banco, ele não valida.

o `dd(Auth::attempt($credenciais));` está sempre retornando `false`.

Alguém saberia o porque ele não autenticar??

Comment: Pergunta: você está usando `Eloquent` mesmo pra autenticar os usuários?

Comment: Sim, estou usando o eloquent..

Comment: Por padrão, o Laravel (inclusive o 5.2) redireciona os usuários autenticados para `/`. A rota `candidato/perfil` (assim como as outras) está configurada em `AuthController`?

Comment: O seu App\Login é um model?

Comment: @Miguel, sim é um model, é a classe `User.php` que vem quando tu baixa o laravel.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida, o problema é no `Auth::attempt()` ele sempre retorna false, mesmo o usúario estando no banco...

Comment: @MeuChapeu Você criptografou a senha com o hash do laravel no banco? se tiver usando outro tipo de criptografia ele não vai autenticar. exemplo $password = Hash::make('123456');

Comment: @MiguelBatista, ainda não criptografei a senha, deixa ela "crua" para fazer os testes...

Comment: @MeuChapeu se você não criptografar o attempt não autentica. Assim só seria possivel  se você fizer a consulta com o model, pegar o objeto e Auth::login($objetoUsuario);

Comment: @MiguelBatista, humm.. interresante não saba desse detalhe.. vou testar aqui...

Comment: para deslogar Auth::logout();

Comment: @MiguelBatista, eu teria que fazer um Hash::make('senha') ali para ele validar? pois não está funcionando, estou criptografando na hora do cadastro, e mesmo assim não vai.. e no $req->input('senha') tbm teria que colocar o Hash? correto? foi o que fiz e nada de funcionar...

Comment: Para validar não deve utilizar hash::make() porque você estaria criando outra criptografia, de uma olhada em https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing você utiliza hash::check('senha', $senhaDoBanco); para comparar a senha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer autenticação pelo Laravel utilizando o método `attempt()` você deve certificar que criptografou a senha com o Hashing do laravel da seguinte forma:

`Hash::make('sua senha')`

no banco de dados ou

`bcrypt('sua senha')`

como especificado [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/hashing#basic-usage).

Para validar a senha

Caso não queira utilizar o `attempt()` por outros motivos,

você deverá fazer a consulta do usuário utilizando o model como por exemplo:

```
$usuario = Usuario::whereEmail($request->get('email'))->first();

ou 

 $usuario = Usuario::where('email','=',$request->get('email'))->first();

if ($usuario && Hash::check($request->get('senha'), $usuario->senha))      {

    Auth::login($usuario);

    return redirect('sua página após logar');   

} else { 
   return redirect('login'); 
}
```